# clock.js, conditionally set eastern or central time

Tags: javascript

I have a perfectly functioning clock.js widget that I'm using  to display date and time on multiple displays throughout our offices in several states.

The offices in the Eastern timezone have no issue, as this defaults to eastern time (our server running the screens for every display is eastern).

However, I want to add a conditional in here (say `if $screenID == 3 {...` so that on the screens in the Central time zone it shows the proper central time.

How should I go about adding a block in here for that condition to show central rather than eastern?

```
 function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    // var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    // sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + " " + ap;

    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    // var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;

    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Which library is this "clock.js" ?

Comment: It's already embedded in this application with no documentation, but is only labeled as clock.js unfortunately. It seems pretty basic though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timezones.

```js
function startTime(screen, loc) {
  var timeZone = "America/Chicago";
  if (screen === 1)
    timeZone = "America/New_York";

  var dateOptions = { weekday: 'long', day: 'numeric', month: 'long', timeZone: timeZone };
  var timeOptions = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone };
  var dt = new Date();

  document.getElementById("myclock" + loc).innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString("en-US", timeOptions);
  document.getElementById("mydate" + loc).innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString("en-NZ", dateOptions);
}

startTime(0, 1);
startTime(1, 2);
```

```html
<div id="myclock1">asdf</div>
<div id="mydate1">asdf</div>
<hr>
<div id="myclock2">asdf</div>
<div id="mydate2">asdf</div>
```